# 'inheritance' of L.ImageOverlay not yielding an image - is it inheritance?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using what I believe is best practice in simulating inheritance in JS (mozilla docs I think) in using the Leaflet library:

```
myoverlay.prototype = Object.create( L.ImageOverlay.prototype );
myoverlay.prototype.constructor = myoverlay;
```

(Previously tried but failed also with

```
myoverlay.prototype = new L.ImageOverlay ()
```

and

```
myoverlay.prototype = new L.ImageOverlay
```

)

I supply my own constructor but as I understand things it is not possible to invoke the inherited class's constructor when it requires parameters, hence doing it retrospectively with 'call':

```
function myoverlay(bounds, image, map)
{
L.ImageOverlay.call(this, image, bounds,{opacity:0.2, errorOverlayUrl:'no-data.png'})
this.addTo(map);
}
```

with the above I see no overlay.
but doing this:

```
function myoverlay(bounds, image, map)
{
this.x =L.imageOverlay(image, bounds,{opacity:0.2, errorOverlayUrl:'no-data.png'});
this.x.addTo(map);
}
```

does work.
I see that the execution of .addTo() creates a number of instance variables, either under 'this' with the former code, under 'this.x' with the latter:

```
_zoomAnimated: true
_map: e
_mapToAdd: e
_leaflet_id:
_events: ...
```

Except this:

```
_image: ...
```

which only appears with the latter.
I would guess that it is this lack in the former case which accounts for no overlay!
but why is it not there? is the retrospective 'call' to the L.ImageOverlay constructor with parameter arguments, in fact NOT equivalent to a 'new ...' invocation ?
or is it potentially a bug?!

nb. the mozilla doc on 'classical' inheritance:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

... but nothing specific to class constructors that take parameters.

Comment: How do you call the newly created constructor? An example call maybe?

Comment: Overlays[x]          = new myoverlay(corners.Bounds[resolution], ximgURL + ".body.png", map);

Comment: From their sources, it looks like their constructor is split into the actual constructor and the `initialize` function which your way of inheriting using the classical js approach just ignore. Have you tried inheriting with their `Class.extend` which looks like it respects their convention? (you'd have to consult their sources to learn the pattern).

Comment: In fact it was the first method I used but forgotten about. I have just repeated it with a negative result.  the _image value is again missing though!

Comment: Welcome to SO! First go through Leaflet dedicated tutorials: [Extending Leaflet: Class Theory](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html) and [Extending Leaflet: Layers](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html). As implied by the Mozilla doc you refer to, JavaScript does not have any "official" class and inheritance system (before ES6). While the doc shows how it can be somehow emulated with `Object.create`, many libraries have used their own scheme, including Leaflet, so you should not assume every lib will behave the same.